# Removing both duplicates (not just the repeated) from a text file?

Tags: regex, macros, rows

By this I mean, erase all rows in a text file that are repeated, NOT just the duplicates. I mean both the row that is duplicated and the duplicated row. This would leave me only with the list of rows that weren't repeated. Perhaps a regular expression could do this in notepad++? But which one? Any other methods?

Comment: Do you have any programming languages installed? Preferably "scripting" languages for a task like this. If so, which languages. And of those which is your preferred language?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a unix-like system, you can use the [uniq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq) command.

```
ezra@ubuntu:~$ cat test.file
ezra
ezra
john
user
ezra@ubuntu:~$ uniq -u test.file
john
user
```

Note, that the similar rows be adjacent.  You'll have to sort the file first if they're not.

```
ezra@ubuntu:~$ cat test.file
ezra
john
ezra
user
ezra@ubuntu:~$ uniq -u test.file
ezra
john
ezra
user
ezra@ubuntu:~$ sort test.file | uniq -u
john
user
```

Comment: If you're not, I propose cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

If you have acess to a regex that supports PCRE style, this is straight forward:

`s/(?:^|(?<=\n))(.*)\n(?:\1(?:\n|$))+//g`

```
(?:^|(?<=\n))     # Behind us is beginning of string or newline
(.*)\n            # Capture group 1: all characters up until next newline
(?:               # Start non-capture group
    \1                # backreference to what was captured in group 1
    (?:\n|$)          # a newline or end of string
)+                # End non-capture group, do this 1 or more times
```

Context is a single string

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $str = 
'hello
this is
this is
this is
that is';

$str =~ s/
          (?:^|(?<=\n))
          (.*)\n
          (?:
              \1
              (?:\n|$)
          )+
  //xg;

print "'$str'\n";

__END__
```

output:

`'hello`
`that is'`

Comment: I think the expression: `(?:^|(?<=\n))` can be simplified to just: `^` if the 'm' "multi-line" mode is on.

Comment: hey thanks buddy. what regexp editor do you recommend? i have editpad pro, regex buddy, and notepad++. Also, how to get this expression input and output in these editors; I wrote them down in the three but I obviously don't know what I'm doing. Something that would enable split screen would be great. (a bit like dreamweaver)

Comment: @ridgerunner - yes it can use just `s/^..//mg` but sometimes explaining multi-line mode is often a headache.

Comment: @user656022 - I just use Perl to run a test, takes 10 seconds. Not big for online testers when I have a good one here.